# Is there a way to re-use a LINQ statement, but alter the property and method being called on that property?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code snippet, and I can't seem to come up with an elegant way to refactor it so I'm not violating copy/paste programming. Please note the snippet is not complete, but I believe it should have the necessary information to provide decent context. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> dataSet = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{ ID = "1", PrimaryName = "Prim", SecondaryName = "Sec"},
        new Person{ ID = "2", PrimaryName = "test", SecondaryName = "Sec2"},
        new Person{ ID = "3", PrimaryName = "test", SecondaryName = "Sec3"}
    };
    string attribute = "LastName";
    OperatorValue queryOperator = OperatorValue.Equal;
    string value = "test";

    switch (attribute)
    {
        case ("LastName"):
            if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.Equal))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.PrimaryName.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.NotEquals))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => !p.PrimaryName.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.StartsWith))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.PrimaryName.StartsWith(value));
            }
            else
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.PrimaryName.Contains(value));
            }
            break;
        case ("FirstName"):
            if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.Equal))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.SecondaryName.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.NotEquals))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => !p.SecondaryName.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.StartsWith))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.SecondaryName.StartsWith(value));
            }
            else
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.SecondaryName.Contains(value));
            }
            break;
        case ("ID"):
            if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.Equal))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.ID.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.NotEquals))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => !p.ID.Equals(value));
            }
            else if (queryOperator.Equals(OperatorValue.StartsWith))
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.ID.StartsWith(value));
            }
            else
            {
                dataSet = dataSet.Where(p => p.ID.Contains(value));
            }
            break;
    }

    foreach (Person person in dataSet)
        Console.WriteLine(person.ID);
}

public enum OperatorValue
{
    Equal,
    NotEquals,
    StartsWith
}

public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryName { get; set; }
}
```

There are more cases in the switch statement which I would like to treat the same way, so you can see this is starting to get ugly fast. I'm trying to come up with a helper method that I could just call for each case, but I'm completely stuck and out of ideas. I appreciate any help.

Comment: There are many ways to refactor. For example, you may want to try creating an extension method which will accept property and operator and it can then perform query on received property using received operator

Comment: This code just looks like a Kludge to patch the real problem.  What error are you getting without the code.

Comment: Please do make your example code reproducible and without errors next time, had to do allot of work just to make it work so I can help you. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I appreciate your time. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the value of `attribute` defines which property you want to select. Apparently these properties are all string properties.

With the value of `operatorValue` you want to select the action with the selected string property: equal, unequal, contains, etc.

It seems to me, that you have an enum OperatorValue, something like this:

```
enum OperatorValue
{
    Equals,
    NotEquals,
    StartsWith,
    Contains,
}
```

I'll write extension methods similar to the already existing [Queryable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netframework-4.8). See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Convert string `queryOperator` to `OperatorValue`:

```
public static OperatorValue ToOperatorValue(this string queryOperator)
{
    // TODO: exception if input null
    return Enum.Parse(typeof(OperatorValue), queryOperator);

    // TODO: decide what to do if queryOperator has not existing enum value
}
```

Usage:

```
string queryOperatorTxt = ...
OperatorValue operator = queryOperatorTxt.ToOperatorValue();
```

Of course we also need a method to convert the string attribute into a propertySelector:

```
public static Expression<Func<Person, string>> ToPropertySelector(this string attributeTxt)
{
    // TODO: check incorrect parameters
    Expression<Func<Person, string>> propertySelector;
    switch (attributeTxt)
    {
        case "LastName":
           propertySelector = (person) => person.PrimaryName;
           break;
        case "FirstName":
           propertySelector = (person) => person.SecondaryName;
           break;
        ... etc

        default:
            // TODO: decide what to do with unknown attributeTxt
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string attributeTxt = ...
Expression<Func<Person, string>> propertySelector = attributeTxt.ToPropertySelector();
```

Now that we know how to convert the queryOperator and attribute, we can create an extension for the Where:

```
public static IQueryable<Person> Where(
    this IQueryable<Person> source,
    Expression<Func<Person, string>> propertySelector,
    OperatorValue operator,
    string value)
{
    // TODO: exceptions if incorrect parameters
    switch (operator)
    {
        case OperatorValue.Equals:
            return source.Where(item => propertySelector(item) == value);

        case OperatorValue.NotEquals:
            return source.Where(item => propertySelector(item) != value);

        case OperatorValue.StartsWith:
            return source.Where(item => propertySelector(item).StartsWith(value);

        case OperatorValue.Contains:
            return source.Where(item => propertySelector(item).Contains(value);

        default:
           // TODO
    }
}
```

Put it all together:

```
IQueryable<Person> dataSet = db.Persons;
string attributeTxt = ...
string queryOperatorTxt = ...
string value = ...

Expression<Func<Person, string>> propertySelector = attributeTxt.ToPropertySelector();
OperatorValue operation = queryOperatorTxt.ToOperatorValue();

IQueryable<Person> queryPersons = dataSet.Where(propertySelector, operation);
```

Well, doesn't that look like a neat LINQ statement!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the code reusable and not having to copy/paste everytime you need want to filter by a new property. You can do the following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> dataSet = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{ ID = "1", PrimaryName = "Prim", SecondaryName = "Sec"},
        new Person{ ID = "2", PrimaryName = "test", SecondaryName = "Sec2"},
        new Person{ ID = "3", PrimaryName = "test", SecondaryName = "Sec3"}
    };
    string attribute = "LastName";
    OperatorValue queryOperator = OperatorValue.Equal;
    string value = "test";

    Func<Person, string> getter = GetFuncForProperty(attribute);
    dataSet = Filter(dataSet, getter, queryOperator, value);

    foreach (Person person in dataSet)
        Console.WriteLine(person.ID);
}

public static IEnumerable<Person> Filter(IEnumerable<Person> source, Func<Person, string> getter, OperatorValue operatorValue, string searchValue)
{
    switch (operatorValue)
    {
        case OperatorValue.Equal:
            return source.Where(p => getter.Invoke(p).Equals(searchValue));
        case OperatorValue.NotEquals:
            return source.Where(p => !getter.Invoke(p).Equals(searchValue));
        case OperatorValue.StartsWith:
            return source.Where(p => getter.Invoke(p).StartsWith(searchValue));
    }

    throw new ArgumentException(operatorValue.ToString() + " is not supported");
}

public static Func<Person, string> GetFuncForProperty(string propertyName)
{
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "ID":
            return (Person person) => person.ID;
        case "FirstName":
            return (Person person) => person.SecondaryName;
        case "LastName":
            return (Person person) => person.PrimaryName;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException(propertyName + " is not supported");
}

public enum OperatorValue
{
    Equal,
    NotEquals,
    StartsWith
}

public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryName { get; set; }
}
```

See it running at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAqvZZ

Comment: I don't think this will translate into SQL (so it will get everything and then filter in-memory), unless you return `IQueryable<Person>` and use `Expression<Func<Person, string>>`